# Regex: parsing GitHub usernames (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, github

I'm trying to parse GitHub usernames (that start with @) from a paragraph of text in order to link them to their associated profiles.

The GitHub username constraints are:

- Alphanumeric with **single** hyphens (no consecutive hyphens)
- Cannot begin or end with a hyphen (if it ends with a hyphen, just match everything up until there)
- Max length of 39 characters.

---

For example, the following text:

> Example @valid hello @valid-username: @another-valid-username, @-invalid @in--valid @ignore-last-dash- an@email.com @another-valid?

The script...

**Should match:**

- @valid
- @valid-username
- @another-valid-username
- @in
- @ignore-last-dash
- @another-valid

**Should ignore:**

- @-invalid
- an@email.com

---

I'm getting reasonably close with JavaScript by using:

```
/\B@((?!.*(-){2,}.*)[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,38}[a-z0-9])/ig
```

But this isn't matching usernames with a single character (such as @a).

Here are my tests to far: https://regex101.com/r/rZ5eW1/2

Is the current regex efficient? And how can I match a single non-hyphen character?

Comment: Hmm... Just thought of an answer, but one question: What would you like it to do in the case of `@hfd.com`? Should it match `@htd` as a username and ignore `.com` or not match anything? Mine does the former. Also, in the case of `@invalid--username`, would you like it to match `@invalid` as a username, or ignore the whole thing?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. `@whatever.com` should match `@whatever` so I guess it makes sense for `invalid--username` to match `invalid`

Comment: In that case, my answer ought to work. I'm not sure it's possible to do something like reject a match if it _would_ be a good one except for one specific thing; maybe with more complicated stuff that I don't know.

Comment: Note that GitHub used to have somewhat looser username validation in the past and accounts got grandfathered in (e.g., https://github.com/artur-).  Support folks told me that hyphens were allowed at the beginning and end, and underscore was allowed as well.  So to eliminate false negatives (but possibly get a few more false positivies) you probably want a simpler regex like `/\B@[a-z0-9_-]{1,39}/gi`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/\B@([a-z0-9](?:-(?=[a-z0-9])|[a-z0-9]){0,38}(?<=[a-z0-9]))/gi
```

Note: When this regex runs into a character or set of characters that can't be in a username (i.e. `.`, `--`), it matches from `@` up until that stopping point. [OP says that's fine](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/48660532?noredirect=1) so I'm rolling with it. So, if the underline is the matched area (NOT the captured area):

```
@abc.123
@abc--123
@abc-
```

This works by using lots of nested groups. [Regex101 has a fantastic breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/2lbe3c/1), but here's mine anyway:

1. `\B`:  This is a builtin means 'not a word boundary', which seems to do the trick, though it may be problematic if something like `someones.@email.com` is a valid email address. At that point, though, it's indistinguishable from the text of someone who doesn't put spaces after punctuation<sup>[[1](https://xkcd.com/1285/)]</sup> when they start a sentence with an @reference.

*Thanks to Honore Doktorr for [pointing out that negative lookbehinds don't exist in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281026/regex-parsing-github-usernames-javascript/30281147?noredirect=1#comment48660783_30281147).*

2. `@`: Just the literal `@` symbol. One of the few places where a character means what it is.
3. `(...)`: The capturing group. The way it's placed means that it *won't* capture the `@` symbol, it'll just *match* it, so it's easier to get the username -- no need to get a substring.
4. `[a-z0-9]`: A character class to match any letter or number. Because of the `i` flag, this also matches capital letters. Because it's the first letter, it *must* be present.
5. `(?:...)`: This is a noncapturing group. It wraps a block of regex in a group without capturing it.
6. `...|...` We have two alternatives, which are...
7. `-(?=[a-z0-9])`: A hyphen, followed immediately by a non-hyphen valid character.
8. `[a-z0-9]`: A valid non-hyphen character.
9. `{0,38}`: Match the noncapturing group between 0 and 38 times, inclusive. Combined with #4, this gives us 39 letters maximum. Anything beyond that will be ignored.
10. `(?<=[a-z0-9])`: This is a *positive* lookbehind, which JS does support. It ensures the last character isn't a `-` -- or rather, is a valid character except hyphen.

This could be 'optimized' a few ways, but honestly, I'd probably use a **much** simpler regex and do some validation after-the-fact on it, e.g.:

```js
// somehow get the prospective username into `user`
if (user.startsWith('-')) { /* reject */ }
if (user.endsWith('-')) { /* reject */ }
if (user.contains('--')) { /* reject */ }
```

At a bare minimum, explain the regex in your code. Feel free to copy-paste mine with credit.

Comment: Great breakdown of the parts.

Answer (score 3):

This expression will also match your one-word usernames.

```
/\B@(?!.*(-){2,}.*)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,37}[a-z0-9])?\b/ig
```

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/gQ3aA6/1). Explanation:

1. `(?!.*(-){2,}.*)`: your negative lookahead asserts that the rest of the pattern *can’t* contain two or more adjacent dashes.
2. `[a-z0-9]`: there *must* be one alphanumeric character immediately after `@`.
3. `(?:[a-z0-9-]{0,37}[a-z0-9])?`: there *may* be anywhere from 0–37 alphanumeric characters or dashes, followed by one alphanumeric character, immediately after #2’s pattern — or there may be none, to cover single-character usernames. *`(?:…)` is for non-capturing grouping.*
4. `\b`: the whole pattern *must* end at a word break (which includes `-`).

Comment: ...I think I understood some of that. Maybe. Could you add an explanation of how it works?

Comment: Coming back to this almost a year later reminds me just how clever this is. Nice job!

Comment: Sending these props to future-me was very kind, as well as clever—thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using this simple `RegEx` I created to grab github usernames from a *google forms* and it works pretty decently (with one very rare caveat):

```
^@\w(-\w|\w\w|\w){0,19}$
```

**Where:**

- `^`: starting of the line
- `@` and `-`: the symbols at and dash themselves.
- `\w`: [A-Za-z0-9_], numbers, letters (both cases) and underlines
- `$`: end of the line
- `{0,19}`: repeat the parenthesis before it from zero to nineteen times

**To summarize:**

- The matched `RegEx` must be an entire line (from `^` to `$`)
- It will start with an `@` followed by a letter (both cases), number or underline (`@A`, `@1` or `@_`)
- Then it will follow one of the three options in the repetition pattern `(...){0,19}`:

  - a dash and a `\w` (1st opt)
  - two `\w` (2nd opt)
  - a single `\w` (3rd opt)

  This will repeat and give the following patterns:
- Zero times: a single letter username
- One time: it can be a two letter username, or three letters, or three characters with a dash in the middle `@w-w`
- More times: it guarantees that the dash is never in the begin or end, also not duplicated, being anywhere else.
- 19 times: if using only 1st and 2nd options, it gives a maximum of `19*2=38` characters, plus the one in the begin equals to `39` characters total. If using anytime the third option, the total size would be smaller.

**Caveat:**

- It does not recognize patterns with `@ww-w...w` (a dash in the third letter and with 39 characters).
- Although it do recognize the pattern `@ww-w...w` if the size is less than 39 characters.

The problem is that to achieve `ww-w` the pattern is broke down as the first `w` standing alone, followed by a single `w` as the third option in the repeated expression (which leaves only 18 to go), followed by another repetition as `w-` (the first option, leaving only 17 to go), and then, with this 17 left, we can only get `17*2=34` characters. That means, the maximum would be 38 (`34+2+1+1`) characters, not 39.

But that is really ok for my purposes, so if you need simplicity, here it is a `RegEx` that can give you pretty good answers. I hope it helps you understand it when translating to `javascript`.